# Setting File Names As Variables In Bash

Tags: bash, variables, find, wildcard, filenames

I want to find an mp4 file in desktop In a random named file and set its name as a variable, and then use the variable later on, in bash.

I have checked the file permissions.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
find /home/administrator/Desktop/*/*.mp4
FILE-NAME=*.mp4

/usr/bin/mkvmerge --output '/home/administrator/Desktop/*/"$FILE-NAME.mp4"' '(' 
'/home/administrator/*/"$FILE-NAME.mp4"' ')' --attachment-name poster.jpg --
attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file 
/home/administrator/Desktop/*/poster.jpg
```

Error:

`Error: The file '/home/administrator/Desktop/*/"$FILE.mp4"' could not be opened for reading: open file error.`

Comment: You need to refer to your variable with $FILE-NAME to expand it. Put /home/administrator/Desktop/*/$FILE-NAME.mp4 in double quotes also.

Comment: Do you mean like this ? `'/home/administrator/Desktop/*/"$FILE-NAME.mp4"' `

Comment: "/home/administrator/Desktop/*/"$FILE-NAME.mp4". No need for the single quotes

Comment: Apparently it needs the single quotes to run but, now it returns this:

/home/administrator/Desktop/Test.sh: line 3: ind: command not found
/home/administrator/Desktop/Test.sh: line 4: FILE-NAME=*.mp4: command not found
Error: The file '/home/administrator/Desktop/*/"$FILE-NAME.mp4"' could not be opened for reading: open file error.

Comment: `FILE-NAME` is not a valid variable name. Hyphens are not allowed in variable names.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended that but I am left with this error: `Error: The file '/home/administrator/Desktop/*/"$FILE.mp4"' could not be opened for reading: open file error.`